Meaning of the item_id field of the add action of Pocket's modify API
I'm trying to use the
modify
Pocket API to batch add several items (URLs) to my to-read list in
Pocket. What is the meaning of the item_id field in the add action
of the modify endpoint? In other actions I think the item_id
refers existing items. But when adding new items, there is no existing
item to refer to. Perhaps the item_id field should just be empty?
In this related answer, it seems like the item_id can just be omitted.
